# Tableview offset changes on reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a table view which has sections and subsections. Subsections show on clicking the sections. I have added a tap gesture recognizer these sections. The action on the tap gesture sets a flag of opened section as 1 and reloads the table view. The code snippet is :

```
func openDrop(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {

    // if else for the particular section and modify data
    let selectedView = gesture.view as! SideMenuView
    self.selectedMenu = selectedView.tag
    if(self.openedMenus[selectedMenu] == -1) {
        self.sideSubMenuUpdate[self.selectedMenu] = self.sideSubMenu[self.selectedMenu]
        self.openedMenus[self.selectedMenu] = 1
        self.sideMenuTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: self.selectedMenu), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    } else {
        self.sideSubMenuUpdate[self.selectedMenu] = []
        self.openedMenus[self.selectedMenu] = -1
        self.sideMenuTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: self.selectedMenu), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    }
}
```

The problem : After the table view reloads, the frame position of tableview changes from (0,0) to (0,20) i.e. the table shifts towards the bottom.

Automatically adjust content insets for view containing table view is false and table has top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint constants as 0 to the view.

Comment: you can use this library, its very easy to use. pease check https://github.com/jackkwok/JKExpandTableView

Comment: I've already implemented the expandable view. Only the layout is creating a problem. I need to solve the bug, I can't change the whole implementation now.